# Change Java Security level

Tags: java, windows, security, java-7

Java 7 update 51 has java security level which is set to HIGH by default. I want to change it to medium by using registry or by adding any files. I observed that manually changing security level to medium from high creates registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\DeploymentProperties]
"deployment.security.level"="MEDIUM"
```

But if i manually create the above registry then java security setting does not change and created registry gets deleted. So I think there must be other files which does it. So how can I change java security setting? I have seen some [articles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html#location) and forum links but didn't get what I wanted. Also this is not to set security level for my customers and it is for my office where number of employees need to change this setting(all are windows OS pc's)  and it will be easy if there is automation like code or a registry entries.

Comment: Is setting this through Java Control Panel a workable option for u?

Comment: You are looking at documentation for Java 6.  Try this instead ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/properties.html

Comment: @StephenC That article has explanation about security settings.But that one does not help me much to find answer for my question.

Comment: @ITresearcher - I think you need to read it again.  It explains what files to put the security settings properties in.

Comment: @ITresearcher: did my answer help you? If it did, i would appreciate if you would mark it as solved. If it didn't help you, please provide feedback so i can try to adjust my answer.

Answer (score 4):

To change the security settings you need to modify the deployment.config of java (not the registry). 
It is located at

> Windows Directory\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.config // system
>   level

or

> User Application Data
>   Folder\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties // user
>   level

You need to add the entry:

**deployment.security.level=MEDIUM**

The documentation on this can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help 
The proper path is

C:\Users\Your_Account_Name\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

enter at the last line

deployment.security.level=MEDIUM

restart the browser and good to go

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been described [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023149).
I was resolved it by downgrading to version 7u25